# powershell start a ScheduledTask when not running

Tags: powershell

I have never written anything is powershell can someone please write me a script to achieve this.

I have a scheduled task `Task_1` that runs at 11am from Task Scheduler, which usually take 1 hour to complete. It sometimes reported as "completed" around 11:20am without any error.

I want to create a new task `Task_2` that runs at 11:30am, but I want it to check on the status of `Task_1`. If `Task_1` is not running, start `Task_2`.

Can someone help me on this script for `Task_2`?

```
if (Get-ScheduledTask | Where TaskName -eq Task_1).State != running
Start Task_1
```

Thank you

Comment: I would take a look at these cmdlets assuming you have new enough version of PS `New-ScheduledTask`, `New-ScheduledTaskAction`, `New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal`, `New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet`, `New-ScheduledTaskTrigger`

Comment: What is Task_1 doing? I don't understand why you can't simply schedule Task_1 for 11:00am and 11:30am and configure it to not start a new instance if it's already running.

Comment: Can anyone help?